# How can Selenium Webdriver get text from mouseover element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape my discord server using selenium to search for messages and get the details of the message, specifically the date and time the messages were sent.

I have been able to get the time from the text contents of the message element, however the date is behind a mouseover hover tooltip (if you have used discord you might know what I mean).

I've tried to search for the way to get the text of the tooltip but none of the ways have worked/the solutions available were not about getting the text. i.e `get_attribute('title')` doesn't work.

For reference the element of the tooltip is:

`<span class="latin12CompactTimeStamp-38a8OU timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampVisibleOnHover-2bQeI4 alt-1uNpEt"><span aria-label="15:03"><i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">[</i>15:03<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">] </i></span></span>`

I can edit and include my python code but I don't think it would help to explain much.

[image]

url is in the form ([https://discord.com/channels/{guild](https://discord.com/channels/%7Bguild) ID}/{channel ID}/{message ID})
*to my knowledge...*

Comment: please add screenshot of the tool tip and also what text you need . Also it would be great if you have the url

Comment: Have done that now

Answer (score 1):

The date is in the aria-label in the span child class

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@class,'latin12CompactTimeStamp')]/span[1]")
```

Then use either

```
print(elem.get_attribute('aria-label'))
print(elem.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've just tried this and the text doesn't return any value, but aria-label returns the time and not the date. However the xpath you gave can be found by the Webdriver so that's a step closer than where I was before

Comment: Does the value pop up after hover?

Comment: No, I could get that action to work either. I fixed my problem by using the message id and getting the timestamp from it... But I still am stuck on getting tooltips to pop up.